# UnknownHostException in Nifi GetHttp processor running inside VirtualBox (Hortonworks Sandbox)

Tags: dns, virtualbox, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I am trying to get data from the following URL:
http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=vehicleLocations&a=sf-muni&r=M&t=0

I have configured Nifi (that is running on Oracle VirtualBox) GetHttp proccesor URL property to the aforementioned URL, however I am getting following exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: webservices.nextbus.com
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
```

I have used following command on both VM and Host machine.

```
nslookup webservices.nextbus.com
```

which outputs following on both VM and Host:

```
Non-authoritative answer: 
Name:    4yu7q.x.incapdns.net 
Address: 192.230.77.86 
Aliases:  webservices.nextbus.com
```

I am using Google DNS (inside /etc/resolv.conf I have following)

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Pinging webservices.nextbus.com is also successful

```
ping webservices.nextbus.com

Pinging 4yu7q.x.incapdns.net [192.230.77.86] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.230.77.86: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 192.230.77.86: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=56
```

What could be the cause for the UnknownHostException and how to fix it?

Comment: I set up the same flow and was able to successfully retrieve the data from that URL. Can you run a simple Java program to try and retrieve the data from the URL and see if the JVM can resolve that hostname outside of NiFi? I haven't seen this issue before.

Comment: Looks like DNS changes weren't picked up from resolv.conf file. Restarting NiFi fixed the issue.

Comment: @Janar you da man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS changes weren't picked up from resolv.conf file. Restarting NiFi fixed the issue.